# Gradle preprocess assets

Tags: android, gradle, gradlew, android-productflavors

I want to do something with assets on build stage. This is my gradle script.

```
project.afterEvaluate{
    prepareDependencies.dependsOn("generateMyAssets")
}

task generateMyAssets() {
    copy {

        from('/') {
            include '**/*.html'
            filter {
                line -> line.replaceAll(/(<img src=\")(?!(.*:.*))/, '<img src="assets:')
            }
        }

        into 'assetsRegxped/'
    }
}
```

My question is, how flexible retrieve name(path) of assets folder in case flavors. Also how i can change only build versions?